# indirect jar conflict between spring-security-rest and guava causing NoSuchMethod error

Tags: grails, guava, grails3, grails-3.1, google-guava-cache

I use grails 3.1.16

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2"
}
```

while running this code:

```
   private LoadingCache<String, Boolean> attempts

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        Integer time = ApplicationContextHolder.getProperty(ApplicationContextHolder.config.time)
        attempts = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(time, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build({ 0 } as CacheLoader)
    }
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Platform.systemNanoTime()J
        at com.google.common.base.LocalCache(Ticker.java:60)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.put(LocalCache.java:2827)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.put(LocalCache.java:4149)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.put(LocalCache.java:4754)
        at com.google.common.cache.Cache$put.call(Unknown Source)
```

After running dependency-report, I found out that the issue was caused by a dependency of the Spring Security REST Plugin: ( com.google.guava:guava-base:r03) - with the same package name "com.google.common.base" and Platform.class with no such method systemNanoTime()

```
|    +--- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava-io:r03
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava-annotations:r03
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava-base:r03
|    |    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava-annotations:r03
```

Any ideas to solve this ?

Answer (score 8):

**Step 1.** Please check with updated dependencies([issue may be reported](https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/issues)):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.RC1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:24.0-jre'
}
```

You can check spring-security-rest [documentation](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/2.0.0.RC1/docs/gapi/index.html?overview-summary.html) and [repo](http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-rest/)
and for guava [documentation](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/) and [repo](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/)

### OR

**Step 2.**

```
compile("org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.RC1") {
            excludes([group: 'com.google.guava:guava'])
}
```

### OR

**Step 3.** in your `build.gradle` you can exclude the compiled classes from the JAR file:

```
jar {
 exclude "com/google/guava/**/**"
}
```

or you can refer [grails documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/plugins.html#_customizing_the_plugin_contents)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried?

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
    compile ("org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2") {
        exclude module: 'guava-base'

        // can also be specified with group
        // exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-base'
    }
}
```

This will exclude the transitive dependency of `guava-base` from `spring-security-rest`.

Comment: i have, but i don't know if it's working since the issue reproduce only sometimes and the dependency tree doesn't update (as written in the documentation)... it's "try and pray"